# get updated cell values after doing HSSFFormulaEvaluator.evaluateAllFormulaCells(hssfWorkbook) in apache poi

Tags: apache-poi

I have a template xls file. I have to copy data to one tab and other tabs have lots of formulas to update itself. After copying data to the first tab , I do :

```
HSSFFormulaEvaluator.evaluateAllFormulaCells(InputBook);
```

But again when I try to access other tabs data by the code :

```
        String input = "temp.xls";
        HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(input)); 
        HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheet("Sheet4");

        Iterator <Row> rowIt = sheet.iterator();   
        while(rowIt.hasNext()) {
           Row row = rowIt.next();
            Cell cell = row.getCell(1);
            System.out.println(cell.getRichStringCellValue());
        }
```

Here I get old data. After evaluating the formula I should be getting updated data . But once I open the xls file all the tabs data are refreshed/updated. It is only through apache poi I am not able to access the updated data.How can I achieve this?

Comment: What happens when you use [evaluateAll()](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/FormulaEvaluator.html#evaluateAll%28%29)? And what happens if you upgrade to the most recent version of Apache POI?

Comment: Same result with evaluateAll().. :( And I use 3.12 version

Comment: How can I refresh the whole workbook?

Comment: That does refresh the whole workbook, as the javadocs I linked to explained! 3.12 isn't the latest version, so what happens when you upgrade?

Comment: Tried with latest version. Same result

Comment: I have a pivot table in the xl. Is evaluateAll() evaluates pivot table or shall I have to add some more lines for that?